# every item of recyclerView open to its own activity or fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an recyclerView which contain items that i retrieve from database, now i want to click on the item, every item of recylerView go to unique activity by its id.

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(itemView.getContext(),detail_activity.class);
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: OKay, By which Id you can move to a particular activity? Like how to know that if I click here then move here?

Comment: every item of recyclerview have an id in database.

Comment: yes id's are 1, 2, 3 ....

Comment: Please paste your adapter class here.

Comment: add the item as a parcelable to the intent

Comment: @Rafsanjani can yo explain it more.

Comment: @Ali adapter work perfectly..

Comment: I know buddy, but first I want to show your adapter then I will tell you how to open activity by particular Id @Alikhan

Comment: Okay, Let me confirm You want to pass ID's or you want to open activity by particular id? @Alikhan

Comment: @Ali i want to open particular activity by id,

Comment: @Alikhan See my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

OnClickItem

```
Intent intent=new Intent(itemView.getContext(),detail_activity.class);
intent.putExtra("id","ITEM_ID");
itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity class

```
String intentValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

Do whatever you want by id.

Answer (score 0):

As i recommend you to create a single Activity and pass the unique id or data from your adapter and set or get data according to this data because if recyclerView data come in large amount like 50 or 100 so its hard to create a new activity for each and every one.  like pass the

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context,your_activity);
intent.putExtras("your_key",""+you_data);
context.startActivity(intent)
```

and get it into your second activity

```
String intentValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

and after this use this id to get the your items details

Comment: yes i have large amount of data.. i have an single activity which contain gridView items.. every item of recyclerView to its own gridview

Comment: so its a good opation you just send a id and fetch the data according to your id from you data base